# How to point branch to master after rebase complete

Tags: git, github

I am not very much clear about git rebase workflow, I try my self to rebase two different branches as mention below.

But I am not able to update my branch to where master is pointing after rebase completed.

Below are the steps which I performed

```
git clone https://github.com/myadmin/testrepo.git
git checkout -b hotfix
git push origin hotfix

modify file "todo.txt" on hotfix branch.

git add todo.txt
git commit -m "todo updates"
git push remote master
```

---

Now I checkout "master" branch

```
git checkout master

modify file "todo.txt" on master branch.
I modify same line which I modify in my "hotfix" branch so I can     generate conflict.

git add todo.txt
git commit -m "todo updates"
git push remote hotfix
```

---

upto now I just forwared both branch "master" and "hotfix" with 1 commit, so I can perform rebase.

Now I rebase with following commands

```
git checkout hotfix
git rebase master
```

so I got the conflict so, I fix all manually with opening file in text editor and again add and commit that file as below.

```
git add todo.txt
git commit -m "resolve conflict"

git rebase --continue
```

till now my rebase is completed, now I wants to move my "master" pointer so I run below command

```
git checkout master
git merge hotfix
```

Now I got my "hotfix" changes to "master" perfectely.

**MY qesestion is start from here.......**

How to point my "hotfix" branch to where "master" is currently poinging after rebase operation ?

Comment: Are you really pushing the branch `hotfix` to `remote`'s `master`, and the branch `master` to `remote`'s `hotfix`?

Comment: You know that rebasing a pushed branch is generally a very bad idea right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
git checkout hotfix
git merge master
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but in this case again it will generate conflict right ? And is this a right flow for rebase or not , pls share your valuable comments

Comment: Seeing that you just merged hotfix into master, merging master into hotfix should just be a fast forward merge, i.e. it should just advance hotfix to point to master. I'm actually surprised that you would need to even do this, as I would assume your merge of hotfix into master itself would just be a FF merge.

Comment: David, So it means after FF after merge of hotfix into master there is not need to update "hotfix" branch .  So I assume workflow I am following is correct ?  Thanks again david

Comment: There should be no need to update `hotfix`. You can confirm this by doing `git rev-parse hotfix` and `git rev-parse master`, and confirming the output of those two are the same. As far as your workflow goes, it looks fine to me. Myself, I prefer to do a merge instead of a rebase when integrating a feature or hotfix (especially when there are conflicts), but that is a personal preference.